# Difference between using unary operator ! and (== false) in if statement

Tags: java

I need to know what is difference between using ! operator and ==false in if statement.

**I know output will be same for both. Am expecting to know internal jvm performance or any memory usage for using false value like that.**

**By using ! operator**

```
if(!MyUtil.isFieldEmpty(String value)){
   System.Out.println("Not Empty");
}
```

**By using ==false**

```
if(MyUtil.isFieldEmpty(String value) == false){
   System.Out.println("Not Empty");
}
```

MyUtil.java

```
public static boolean isFieldEmpty(String value){
  if ((value == null) || (value.trim().length() == 0) || value.equals("null")) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Execute and see.. the best way to learn :)

Comment: just remember, in most case, `!` is _not_ and `=` is _yes_

Answer (score 4):

In terms of performance, there may (or may not, likely not) be a *slight* edge in favor of using the simpler (that is, not including `==`) form.  Otherwise, they're **virtually identical.**

But that's really not the point here.

Writing your boolean expressions in the form of `if(booleanMethod() == true|false)` is entirely **redundant.**  That decreases readability in some aspects, introduces unnecessary code and evaluation statements, and most modern IDEs/Java style checkers will complain about expressions like that.

As an example, [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.2.5/rules/design.html) will whine about this being a case of "SimplifyBooleanExpressions".

If your left-hand expression is a boolean, and all you *need* is a boolean, then just use the left-hand expression.   `!MyUtil.isFieldEmpty(String value)` is perfectly acceptable.

Also, as an aside, your boolean method could also do with some refactoring, too.  It boils down to this:

```
public static boolean isFieldEmpty(String value) {
     return (value == null) || (value.trim().length() == 0) || value.equals("null");
}
```

This is for the same reason:  redundancy.  You're basically saying, "if this is true, or this is true, or this is true, then return true."  Turns out that's just the result of the natural evaluation of the expression.

Why not just return the result of the expression?  [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.2.5/rules/design.html) would consider this a case of "SimplifyBooleanReturns".

Comment: In addition: I just compiled both, the `!` and the `==false`. The compiler produced the same bytecode instruction `IFNE`. So there will not be any performance improvement.

Comment: I would imagine that the compiler would be smart enough to optimize it out, although that's just the standard JVM - can't speak to any other third party Java compiler.

Comment: Yes you're right. Maybe I find a hint someday in the JVM spec and/or JLS. :)

Answer (score 0):

They're essentially the same. In any Java `if` statement, if you merely input a boolean, the if will compare the boolean there to `true`. So say I have:

```
boolean x = false;
if(!x)
return x;
```

This will return `false`. `!x` is equal to `true`. The same would happen for

```
boolean x = false;
if(x == false)
return x;
```

Basically, there is no difference in execution.

Answer (score 0):

`!` Operator just convert the true into false and false  into true but `==false`  only check for the condition for false value

For example

```
boolean flag = true;
//its true
if(flag) {
}

//its false
if(!flag) {

}

flag = false ;


//its false
if(flag) {
}

//its true
if(!flag) {

}
```

But in **==false** you can only check the false condition and it will returns true if and only if the left side value is false

```
boolean flag = true;
//its false
if(flag == false) {

}

flag = false;

//its true
if(flag == false){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The very simple difference is that the unary operator (`!`) does a negation of the boolean value returned from the method and uses that as for the `if` statement.

Whereas the `==` is the comparison operator which compares the return value of the method to `false`(the value specified on the RHS).

`!false` yields `true` - does negation 
`true == false` yields `false` - does comparison

Answer (score 0):

`!` negates a boolean expression:

- **`!true`:** is `false`
- **`!false`:** is `true`

while `something == false` will evaluate to:

- **`true`:** if `something` is `false`
- **`false`:** if `something` is `true`

In this case both expressions will evaluate to the same value:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(!false);
    System.out.println(false == false);
    System.out.println(!true);
    System.out.println(true == false);
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

The `!` operator simply invert your condition.

```
boolean a = false;
if(!a) // !a == true
   //if always runns
else
   //else never run
```

The  `== false` check if your condition is false or not.

```
if(a == false) //since 'a = false'
   //if runs
else
  //never run
```

in both conditions `if` executes.

Answer (score 0):

Both will give the same output.

In the first method,

The NOT operator(!) will do the negation of the boolean value returned.

In the second method,
It will check wheather the boolean returned value is false or not.

The second method is directly checking whether the boolean returned value is false or not and in the first method it is indirectly checking for false value. Bcas, !true = false and !false = true